# Substring extraction with pandas / regex

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I'm trying to use the built in pandas method .str.extract to extract a substring from within a column in a dataframe I have imported. The entries within the column all follow this structure:

```
x.xx% Test1 Test2 Test3 XYZ|ZYX Oct 2018
```

So essentially it is always a float %, following by a string (which doesn't always have the same length of words), followed by a three letter code which is either XYZ or ZYX and a date afterwards.

I'm trying to extract the Test1, Test2 and Test3 from the example above, meaning I want to strip out the percentage at the beginning, and where XYZ|ZYX occur I want everything after gone (including the three letter code).

I've been reading up on regex all morning but I'm struggling a bit to build some code using pandas extract that can pull out exactly what I want. Any suggestions? Furthest I've gotten is the below, which only pulls through the percentages at the beginning (was trying to split it into three categories):

```
.str.extract('(\d\.\d+%.)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern with a lookahead to determine when to stop matching.

```
([\w\s]+?)(?=\w{3}\|)'
```

**Details**

```
(               # first capture group
    [\w\s]+?    # match letters or whitespaces
)
(?=             # lookahead
    \w{3}       # fixed length 3 chars
    \|          # literal `|`
)
```

---

```
s = pd.Series(['x.xx% Test1 Test2 Test3 XYZ|ZYX Oct 2018'])
s.str.extract(r'([\w\s]+?)(?=\w{3}\|)', expand=False)

0     Test1 Test2 Test3 
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex you can you could be the following:

```
r"(\d\.\d+%.)(.*)\s([A-Z]{3})\s([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})\s([0-9]{4}$)"
```

where `\d\.\d+%.` matches the percentage

`[A-Z]{3}` matches the letter code

`[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}` matches the month

`[0-9]{4}$` matches the year, at the end

`.*` matches the remaining, thus the tests.

the `\s` match a single space, and it's outside the matches.

The resulting code could be something like this:

```
import re

string = "3.14% Test1 Test2 Test3 XYZ Oct 2018"

matches = re.findall(r"(\d\.\d+%.)(.*)\s([A-Z]{3})\s([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})\s([0-9]{4}$)", string)[0]

percentage = matches[0] 
mytest = matches[1].split(' ')
letter_code = matches[2]
month = matches[3]
year = matches[4]


print(percentage) # 3.14%
print(mytest) # ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
print(letter_code) # XYZ
print(month) # Oct
print(year) # 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Positive Lookbehind :

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=%)(\s.+)?XYZ|ZYX'
text="""x.xx% Test1 Test2 Test3 XYZ|ZYX Oct 2018


x.xx% Test1 Test2 Test3 ZYX|XYZ Oct 2018"""

for i in re.findall(pattern,text):
    data=re.sub(re.escape('ZYX|'),' ',i)
    if data.split():
        print(data.split())
```

output:

```
['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
```